# MAILTO not adding mails to queue until 9pm

Tags: email, postfix, cron

I'm using postfix on CentOS to send out mails from crontab (using MAILTO=). The mails do send, but only at 21:01, regardless of the time that the cronjob ran. If I run multiple jobs, all of the mails are saved up and sent together at this time, rather than being sent out as soon as the job completes. My crontab looks like this:

```
MAILTO=myaddress@domain.com
MAILFROM=sendaddress@domain.com
15 15 * * * sudo - u someuser sh /path/to/script/
```

Checking /var/log/maillog, entries only appear in the log at 21:01, like it doesn't try and send them until then. I know the cronjobs finish long before then, because the output that is emailed to me includes timestamps for when the script starts and finishes. The postfix service is running and not reporting any errors

Is this caused by a piece of config somewhere that I can change? How can I make sure the mails are sent out as soon as the job finishes running?

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is caused by systemd killing the mail delivery process before it can deliver the mail.  There is some debate over whether this is a good design.

Apparrently the solution to this is to configure any systemd perocess that generates emails  using `/usr/bin/sendmail` (which is in your instance another name or symlink for postfix)  as a forking service.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I just realised that what I thought was the issue was not the issue at all, I'd called for a red herring: the box shuts off at 9, which is why emails were being sent then. The job was hanging until then, hence the mail not being sent